# How to convert between the unicode forms: string, name, number

Tags: bash, perl, one-liner

I have been lately using unicode more often and wondered if there is a command line tool to convert unicode between its forms.

Would be nice to be able to say:

```
uni_convert "☃" --string
```

And know that the string is defined in unicode as a "SNOWMAN".

Answer (score 8):

Perl's [Unicode-Tussle](https://metacpan.org/dist/Unicode-Tussle) distribution comes with the useful `uniprops`.

```
$ uniprops '☃'
U+2603 ‹☃› \N{SNOWMAN}
...

$ uniprops 'U+2603'
U+2603 ‹☃› \N{SNOWMAN}
...

$ uniprops 'SNOWMAN'
U+2603 ‹☃› \N{SNOWMAN}
...
```

If you're writing code, you'll want [charnames](https://metacpan.org/pod/charnames).

| Want | Have | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$code` | `$char` | `ord($char)` |
| `$code` | `$name` | `charnames::vianame($name)` |
| `$char` | `$code` | `chr($code)` |
| `$char` | `$name` | `chr(charnames::vianame($name))` |
| `$name` | `$code` | `charnames::viacode($code)` |
| `$name` | `$char` | `charnames::viacode(ord($char))` |

`vianame` accepts official aliases (e.g. `LF` for `LINEFEED`). You'll need to parse `U+` notation yourself if wish to accept it. (`$code = hex(s/^U\+//r);`)

Example:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature      qw( say );
use experimental qw( regex_sets );     # Safe. Optional since 5.36.

use utf8;                              # Source encoded using UTF-8.
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";   # Terminal provides/expects UTF-8.

use charnames qw( :full );
use Encode    qw( decode_utf8 );

@ARGV == 1
   or die("usage\n");

my $s = decode_utf8($ARGV[0]);

for my $cp ( unpack "W*", $s ) {
   my $ch = chr($cp);
   if ( $ch =~ /(?[ \p{Print} - \p{Mark} ])/ ) {   # Not sure if good enough.
      printf "‹%s› ", $ch;
   } else {
      print "--- ";
   }

   printf "U+%X ", $cp;

   say charnames::viacode($cp);
}
```

```perl
$ uni_id ☃
‹☃› U+2603 SNOWMAN

$ uni_id çà
‹ç› U+E7 LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
‹à› U+E0 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
```

Other resources:

- [Unicode::UCD](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::UCD)

  Provides accsess at the information found in the [Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/).
- The [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/) is more than characters and properties.
- [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops)
- `unichars` from [Unicode-Tussle](https://metacpan.org/dist/Unicode-Tussle) (e.g. `unichars '\p{Hiragana}'`)

Answer (score 2):

I separated the code into a file and created a repo:
https://github.com/poti1/uni_convert

Comment: Why not just use an actual perl script file instead of a huge one-liner wrapped in a shell function?

Comment: Oh, and [Term::ANSIColor](https://perldoc.perl.org/Term::ANSIColor) is useful instead of hardcoded escape sequences.

Comment: Instead of having a file per script or function, I tend to add these to my bashrc. When the script is big enough (like now ), I'd move it to a separate file.

Comment: I've seen Term::ANSIColor used by others. I guess its better than using the escape characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk to do that.

Download [this file](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NamesList.txt) from unicode.org that provides the latest names.

Then:

```
q=$(printf '%x\n' \'☃)
awk '/^[[:xdigit:]]+/{
    str=$0
    sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    names[$1]=str
}
END{ print names[q] }
' q="$q" names.txt
```

Prints:

```
SNOWMAN
```

If you want to go the other way:

```
cp=$(awk '/^[[:xdigit:]]+/{
    str=$0
    sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    other_names[str]=$1
}
END{ print other_names[q] }
' q="SNOWMAN" names.txt)

echo -e "\u${cp}"
```

Prints:

```
☃
```

If you have GNU awk you can easily convert the hex index into decimal and can print from within. This allows a single source file to be used and go one way or the other by defining `q` or `r`:

```
gawk '/^[[:xdigit:]]+/{
    str=$0
    sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    names[$1]=str
    other_names[str]=$1
}
END{ print q ? names[q] : sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" other_names[r])) }
' r='SNOWMAN' names.txt
☃

gawk '/^[[:xdigit:]]+/{
    str=$0
    sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/,"",str)
    names[$1]=str
    other_names[str]=$1
}
END{ print q ? names[q] : sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" other_names[r])) }
' q=$(printf '%x\n' \'☃) names.txt
SNOWMAN
```

Comment: Re "*Download this file from unicode.org that provides the latest names.*", Don't forget the [aliases](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/NameAliases.txt)